# Attempt to copy a file denied by permissions, but why?

Tags: finder, permission, copy-paste

I have a folder which I wish to copy from my Macbook Air (OSX 10.10.5) onto a USB attached hard disk.  When I try to copy the folder, some files are copied, then the copy aborts with the message: *The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access “PT3 Summary and Comments SM358 TMA01.htm”.*  If I just copy that file alone, I am asked to enter my password, and then the file is copied successfully.

The permissions for *(me)* are read/write for the file, and for the source and target folders.  Any idea why I can't copy the whole folder?

Answer (score 3):

This problem may occur because of wrong ownership. Try to run following command to change ownership for your user:

```
sudo chown -R $(id -un):$(id -gn) path_to_your_directory
```

In this example, `sudo` will give you needed permissions to perform operation, `chown` is a command to change ownership, `-R` will make operation recursive against target folder, `$(id -un)` is your current user name `$(id -gn)` is your current group name, `path_to_your_directory` shold be a path to folder you want to fix ownership.

Comment: Unless an ACL interferes.  I have seen Time Machine in a file restore improperly copy the ACLs from the backup.  I've even seen it put ACLs on the parent directory of the destination.

Comment: toma, thanks.  And an apology: I'm not very familiar with Stack, and in attempting to post this I got confused by the presence of WGroleau's comment and pressed the 'vote' arrows thinking I was moving up or down the thread, so I voted your answer up twice and down once.  :-(   Before I apply your recommended procedure, can I find out who the owner currently is?  That might help me to understand how the problem arose.

Comment: @NigelMartin you can type `ls -l path_to_problem_file` to see who is owner.

Comment: The owner appears to be me, so I think that WGroleau's comment about ACL may be the problem.  I think the need to copy the file is not great enough to chase this further.  Thanks.